# Writing a BPSK Demodulator

Tags: gnuradio, bpsk

As part of a larger project, I've been attempting to implement a demodulator for [RDS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio_Data_System), a digital transmission standard in FM broadcasting, in software with C++. I've easily been able to get as far as obtaining the BPSK data stream, but I've been unable to figure out how to demodulate it into binary bits I can sync to.

The RDS data stream below is BPSK encoded at 1187.5 symbols/sec. As far as I understand it, BPSK is encoded by having a clock sine wave at the symbol rate, 1187.5 Hz, and then each cycle shifting the phase by 180 degrees to indicate a "1" or not changing it to indicate a "0" before differential decoding. I have an understanding of analog signals, but I'm pretty clueless when it comes to digital modulation like BPSK, so there's a good chance my understanding is wrong.

[image: BPSK Signal]

I'm attempting to make my decoder for this produce the same output as the [GNURadio Clock Recovery MM](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/master/gr-digital/lib/clock_recovery_mm_ff_impl.cc) component, given the same input. It outputs an analog signal [-1,1] for each symbol clocked, which I can then binary slice to obtain each bit. While this implementation works, and while I could simply accept that implementation and use it in my own decoder, I do not understand it and as far as I'm concerned it operates on magic. There are a [couple](https://edfuentetaja.github.io/sdr/m_m_gnu_radio_analysis/) of [excellent](https://www.tablix.org/%7Eavian/blog/archives/2015/03/notes_on_m_m_clock_recovery/) writeups about this particular component, but specifically I don't understand how the [interpolation part](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/1a0be2e6b54496a8136a64d86e372ab219c6559b/gr-filter/lib/mmse_fir_interpolator_ff.cc) of it behaves. Interpolation appears to use a bunch of FIR filters with [seemingly arbitrary numbers](https://github.com/gnuradio/gnuradio/blob/1a0be2e6b54496a8136a64d86e372ab219c6559b/gr-filter/include/gnuradio/filter/interpolator_taps.h) of taps. I don't know why this number of taps were chosen or why we even need to interpolate to begin with, as I'm already sampling well above the symbol rate.

Additionally, I've also looked into the BPSK demodulator in [REDHAWK-SDR](https://github.com/RedhawkSDR/BPSK/blob/master/cpp/BPSK.cpp). While I couldn't get it to work in my own project, I feel that it's very promising. The unit tests used in that project even operate on the same symbol rate as RDS.

**My Implementation**

I've attempted to write my own decoder using my understanding of BPSK, but I haven't been able to make it work or produce anything remotely like what comes out of the known-good GNURadio decoder. Here are the steps that I believe should be taken, although there are a good chance these are wrong.

- Read an input sample stream at a known sample rate
- Lock onto the 1187.5 Hz (symbol rate) carrier, perhaps with a PLL?
- Clock a bit each time the sample changes sign
- Each time the phase gets inverted, the next bit clocked would be 1. Perhaps interpret sudden increase in error in the PLL as this?

However, this leads to the question of how to lock onto the carrier. Since it's always changing phase to indicate bits, how do I lock onto it to begin with?

**tl;dr;**

Is there any chance someone could assist me with writing a working BPSK demodulation? Even pseudocode would be greatly appreciated. Help understanding the interpolation within the GNURadio implementation would also be appreciated. I've just about fried my brain trying to understand how this works. Thanks!

Comment: Oof.  There's a lot to unpack here.  My recommendation would be to stick with the [symbol sync](https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Symbol_Sync) block for now.  When you build maturity and comfortability with digital comms, go back and replace the block with your own code. It sounds like you're trying to bite off a lot right now.